# AWS CloudWatch Log Group Not Created through Django Logging

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a Django application in which I am trying to do logging on to AWS CloudWatch. I have added the following  code in my settings.py file:

```
CLOUDWATCH_LOGS_BOTO3_CLIENT = boto3.client('logs',
  aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  region_name=AWS_REGION_NAME
)
AWS_LOG_GROUP = 'MyLogGroup'
AWS_LOG_STREAM = 'Mystream'
AWS_LOGGER_NAME = 'watchtower-logger'

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'aws': {
            'format': u"%(asctime)s [%(levelname)-8s] %(message)s [%(pathname)s:%(lineno)d]",
            'datefmt': "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'watchtower': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'watchtower.CloudWatchLogHandler',
                     'boto3_client': CLOUDWATCH_LOGS_BOTO3_CLIENT,
                     'log_group': AWS_LOG_GROUP,
                     'stream_name': AWS_LOG_STREAM,
            'formatter': 'aws',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        AWS_LOGGER_NAME: {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['watchtower'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
    },
}
```

For logging, I am using the following code in my views:

```
import logging
from django.conf import settings
logger = logging.getLogger(settings.AWS_LOGGER_NAME)
logger.error("this is error message")
```

The user whose access/secret key I am using, has full access to cloudwatch logs but log group and log stream is not created in cloudwatch. And there is no error thrown as well. Per my understanding, the above code will create the log group and log stream in cloud watch if not already created.

Comment: I have a similar issue. For me the log group is created, but not the stream.

Comment: At least, are you able to see log statements in the console/terminal?

Comment: @DilLip_Chowdary yes